# Theorem linebreak in an itemize environment

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment, theorems, amsthm

I'm using the `itemize` environment to take notes and sometimes I want to add definitions and theorems in the flow.

However, `amsthm` adds a linebreak between the item bullet and the theorem statement, so they are not aligned.

Here's the fabled minimal working example :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{deff}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item In line.
\item \begin{deff}
This is not in line.
\end{deff}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a manual vertical skip back to the baseline of the `\item` (a total of `\baselineskip` plus `\topsep`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}    
\newtheorem{deff}{Definition}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.48\linewidth}p{.48\linewidth}@{}}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item In line.
  \item \leavevmode\par\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\topsep}\begin{deff}
  This is in line.
  \end{deff}
  \end{itemize} &
  \begin{itemize}
  \item In line.
  \item \textbf{Definition 1.} \itshape This is in line.
  \end{itemize}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The `tabular` arrangement is merely to show the equivalence. I don't think there's much use/advantage is making this part of the definition of `deff`, as theorems are meant to usually stand on their own.

Comment: Meh, I can't upvote your answer. Anyway thanks, it works fine, but I wish there was something more pretty than that. It's just that my document is all made of bullets of various depth (using the `outline` package). Also, I realized that it already worked when I don't import `amsthm`.

Comment: @Neuschwanstein: If all you're using is a bunch of bullets and never setting a theorem (or `deff`) on a line of its own, then you could update the definition of `deff` by adding `\let\olddeff\deff
\renewcommand{\deff}{\leavevmode\par\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\topsep}\olddeff}` to your document preamble. Now you can use it and it will always "jump up".